# Programmable GHz signals

Tags: generator, function-generator

I would like to generate custom waves in the gigahertz range. With beginner FPGAs like the DE0-Nano or microcontrollers like the Arduino, I can only generate waves up to the kilohertz range.

What tools or boards should I look into to start generating at this frequency?

Comment: What type of waves do you want to generate?

Comment: I want to generate square waves

Comment: How square?  What rise times do you need, what frequency? What pulse width resolution?  What is the purpose of generating these signals?

Comment: Gigahertz PLL chip (TI makes a couple, probably others too) and a equally fast digital buffer (Analog Devices, On Semi, and a couple of smaller vendors). Details depend on your actual specs (range of frequencies, etc)

Comment: YOu need to learn to use RF connectors, stripline 50 Ohm impedance and preferably semi-rigid coax before you learn anything else.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Really? That's like saying to a newborn, you need to learn your alphabet before you can say 'Mama'.

Comment: Buy an AD9361 complete RF tranceiver evaluation board. Works as sig-gen and analyser for 70MHz to 6GHz. Play with it, say mama. You might even find some FOSS SDR software for it. It won't do square waves though, you won't be able to do that until you've learned your alphabet, and done a PhD in EngLit.

Comment: @Neil_UK  No I see it as you have to understand Ohms Law before you play around with passives and impedance   that you dont wonder why it fails when you put a 0.1uF to try to suppress ripple on the supply when caps of that size and not wonder why LO leakage occurs without understanding cross talk of adjacent tracks in parallel, or wonder why the LDO performs poorly to GHz step loads.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75   I think actuality for most people lies between the two. We get to understand Ohm's Law by playing with passives, meter and power supply, *and* by reading around to see what we ought to be looking for. It usually takes nature, on the bench, to bludgeon a concept into our heads. Hence I suggested starting with a working EVM board, as there is of course not a snowball in Hades' chance that the user could construct something out of bare ICs. The hidden agenda is of course you can make an SDR (a spectrum analyser) out of it!

Comment: WHat I mean is that s parameters must be thoroughly understood the user has adequate experience with Spectrum and Vector analyzer doing calibration Return loss etc and knows the difference between a microwave balun and an impedance transformer, else, they end up with thinking everything can be solved with microcode.